# Missing AzureRmProfileProvider module

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-runbook

I'm currently in Azure trying to execute a run book using a PowerShell script and my script spits out an error staying that it cannot find this class:
Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Common.Authentication.Abstractions.AzureRmProfileProvider

Can you help find out how I can add this class to my script?

Provided below is my script:

```
[CmdletBinding()]
[OutputType([string])]
Param
(
  # VM Name
  [Parameter(Mandatory = $true,
      ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = $true,
  Position = 0)]
  $VMName
)

$VerbosePreference = 'Continue' #remove when publishing runbook

#region Runbook variables
Write-Verbose -Message 'Retrieving hardcoded Runbook Variables'
$Resourcegroupname = 'scriptextensiondemo-rg'
$ExtensionName = 'WindowsUpdate'
$APIVersion = '2017-03-30'
$ScriptExtensionUrl = 'https://[enteryourvaluehere].blob.core.windows.net/script/Install-WindowsUpdate.ps1'
#endregion

#region Connection to Azure
Write-Verbose -Message 'Connecting to Azure'
$connectionName = 'AzureRunAsConnection'

try
{
  # Get the connection "AzureRunAsConnection "
  $servicePrincipalConnection = Get-AutomationConnection -Name $connectionName         

  'Logging in to Azure...'
  Add-AzureRmAccount `
  -ServicePrincipal `
  -TenantId $servicePrincipalConnection.TenantId `
  -ApplicationId $servicePrincipalConnection.ApplicationId `
  -CertificateThumbprint $servicePrincipalConnection.CertificateThumbprint 
}
catch 
{
  if (!$servicePrincipalConnection)
  {
    $ErrorMessage = "Connection $connectionName not found."
    throw $ErrorMessage
  }
  else
  {
    Write-Error -Message $_.Exception.Message
    throw $_.Exception
  }
}
#endregion

#region Get AccessToken
Write-Verbose 'Get Access Token'
$currentAzureContext = Get-AzureRmContext
$azureRmProfile = [Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Common.Authentication.Abstractions.AzureRmProfileProvider]::Instance.Profile
$profileClient = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ResourceManager.Common.RMProfileClient -ArgumentList ($azureRmProfile)
$token = $profileClient.AcquireAccessToken($currentAzureContext.Subscription.TenantId)
#endregion 

#region Get extension info
Write-Verbose -Message 'Get extension info'
$Uri = 'https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{0}/resourceGroups/{1}/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/{2}/extensions/{3}?api-version={4}' -f $($currentAzureContext.Subscription), $Resourcegroupname, $VMName, $ExtensionName, $APIVersion
$params = @{
  ContentType = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
  Headers     = @{
    'authorization' = "Bearer $($token.AccessToken)"
  }
  Method      = 'Get'
  URI         = $Uri
}
$ExtensionInfo = Invoke-RestMethod @params -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
if (!($ExtensionInfo)) 
{
  Write-Verbose 'No Custom Script Extension Configured. Please do an initial script configuration first'
  #region configure custom script extension
  $Uri = 'https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{0}/resourceGroups/{1}/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/{2}/extensions/{3}?api-version={4}' -f $($currentAzureContext.Subscription), $Resourcegroupname, $VMName, $ExtensionName, '2017-03-30'

  $body = @"
{
  "location": "westeurope",
  "properties": {
    "publisher":  "Microsoft.Compute",
    "type": "CustomScriptExtension",
    "typeHandlerVersion": "1.4",
    "autoUpgradeMinorVersion": true,
    "forceUpdateTag": "InitialConfig",
    "settings": {
       "fileUris" : ["$ScriptExtensionUrl"],
       "commandToExecute": "powershell -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -file Install-WindowsUpdate.ps1"
    }
  }
}
"@

  $params = @{
    ContentType = 'application/json'
    Headers     = @{
      'authorization' = "Bearer $($token.AccessToken)"
    }
    Method      = 'PUT'
    URI         = $Uri
    Body        = $body
  }

  $InitialConfig = Invoke-RestMethod @params
  $InitialConfig
  exit
  #endregion
}
#endregion

#region Get Extension message info
Write-Verbose 'Get Extension message info'
$Uri = 'https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{0}/resourceGroups/{1}/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/{2}/extensions/{3}?$expand=instanceView&api-version={4}' -f $($currentAzureContext.Subscription), $Resourcegroupname, $VMName, $ExtensionName, $APIVersion
$params = @{
  ContentType = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
  Headers     = @{
    'authorization' = "Bearer $($token.AccessToken)"
  }
  Method      = 'Get'
  URI         = $Uri
}
$StatusInfo = Invoke-RestMethod @params
#$StatusInfo
[regex]::Replace($($StatusInfo.properties.instanceView.SubStatuses[0].Message), '\\n', "`n")
#endregion

#region Update Script Extension
try
{
  Write-Verbose 'Update Script Extension'
  $Uri = 'https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{0}/resourceGroups/{1}/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/{2}/extensions/{3}?api-version={4}' -f $($currentAzureContext.Subscription), $Resourcegroupname, $VMName, $ExtensionName, '2017-03-30'

  $body = @"
{
  "location": "westeurope",
  "properties": {
    "publisher":  "Microsoft.Compute",
    "type": "CustomScriptExtension",
    "typeHandlerVersion": "1.4",
    "autoUpgradeMinorVersion": true,
    "forceUpdateTag": "$(New-Guid)",
    "settings": {
       "fileUris" : ["$ScriptExtensionUrl"],
       "commandToExecute": "powershell -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -file Install-WindowsUpdate.ps1"
    }
  }
}
"@

  $params = @{
    ContentType = 'application/json'
    Headers     = @{
      'authorization' = "Bearer $($token.AccessToken)"
    }
    Method      = 'PUT'
    URI         = $Uri
    Body        = $body
  }

  $Updating = Invoke-RestMethod @params
  $Updating
}
catch
{
  Write-Error -Message $_.Exception.Message
  throw $_.Exception
}
#endregion
```

Comment: Unable to find type [Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Common.Authentication.Abstractions.AzureRmProfileProvider].
At line:74 char:19
+ ... RmProfile = [Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Common.Authentication.Abstracti ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (Microsoft.Azure...ProfileProvider:TypeName) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TypeNotFound

Comment: Provided above is the error that i get

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is likely to be that you're running outdated Azure Modules or at least they don't match with the one you have installed in your computer. Try updaing the Azure modules in your Automation Account. Also make sure the modules that you're using are included as well.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Nothing related with outdated Azure modules in my case.

Problem comes from the fact that ps was not able to find the type during parsing but it's available during execution. So simply "cheating" the parser through storing the commandlet within a literal executed with invoke-command it works:

```
$profile = Invoke-Expression "[Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Common.Authentication.Abstractions.AzureRmProfileProvider]::Instance.Profile"
```

Regards.